# My text currently take up the entire space on my page horizontally. I need to be able to control how much space text and images take up

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/evie4411/pen/geWzNM

I would like to have control of how wide my text is.
And both < hr > elements, I would like to extend and retract depending on the width of the text within them.

Right now, the text spreads right across the screen and I would like it to fit within the width of the menu... but I would need flexibility when I work on other elements of my site.

Below, is the css for the whole screen element an it has worked for me well so far across all pages, and i would love if this could stay the same- I am scared of my site looking like a bundle of margins and borders- please see the code pen for the rest

```
.outer {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Many Thanks!!

Comment: add max-width to the text

Comment: CSS properties for `width` and `max-width` are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
max-width: 80%;
```

should do the trick.

You can also use padding.
For example:

```
{
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a container class for your text so you can limit the width of all elements inside easily. Of course you could also just add width to your body but like this you can still have elements that are outside of the width restriction.

This is an easy setup for what I just explained:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <hr/>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```